# Check value of two-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, search, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
array(2) { 
          [0]=> array(1) { ["cate_id"]=> string(2) "14" }
          [1]=> array(1) { ["cate_id"]=> string(2) "15" }
         }
```

How can I check if the value 14 exists in the array without using a for loop?

I've tried this code:

```
var_dump(in_array('14',$categoriesId));exit;
```

but it returns `false`, and I do not know why.

Comment: dont you want to use `foreach` too ?

Comment: what is the reason you don't want to use a loop?

Comment: it too must for loop,in this code I just expect to check value has exist or not in array.

Comment: any solution (even serialize) loops the array. Maybe your solution could be to have the "cate_id" as an index key?
The nyou could check using array_key_exists($theCateIdYouAreLookingFor,$yourArray). You'd have to consider this when you build up this array.

Comment: yes,it only one way that we must use for loop, sorry all for my new php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder why you don't need a `for`. Well a quickest way would be to **`serialize`** your array and do a **`strpos`**.

```
$yourarray = array('200','3012','14');
if(strpos(serialize($yourarray),14)!==false)
{
echo "value exists";
}
```

**`Warning :`** Without using looping structures you cannot guarantee the value existence inside an array. Even an `in_array` uses internal looping structures. So as the comments indicate you will get a false positive if there is `1414` inside the `$yourarray` variable. That's why I made it a point in the first place.

If you need to find a specific value in an array. You have to loop it.

Comment: it not work for me,I expect check value has exist or not in array, so I don't use for loop

Comment: assume the array is like `array(1,1,1,1,1,1 ... ) (15 times)` , your answer will return true, but there is no **14** in the array

Comment: question:
array(2) { 
          [0]=> array(1) { ["cate_id"]=> string(2) "141" }
          [1]=> array(1) { ["cate_id"]=> string(2) "15" }
         }
if(strpos(serialize($yourarray),14)!==false)
what would return ?

Comment: or even `array('141414')`

Comment: yes,it only one way that we must use for loop, sorry all for my new php

Answer (score 2):

Do this :

```
var_dump(in_array("14",array_map('current',$categoriesId))); //returns true
```

Comment: `in_array` does use internal looping structures. Your comment **`Do this (without loop) :` is plainly wrong.**

Comment: I saw your updated answer, makes sense. I'll remove mine too . good luck